# JSLink on Public Facing Site

Tags: jslink

I'm just learning about this JSLink technology and have a simple question.

Does it work on public facing sites because it's not for me. Seems nothing works on public site.

What I've done:

1. copied a js file from online
2. uploaded it to my public site master page gallery
3. tried to set content type to "javascript display template" but that didn't work (surprise)
4. pointed the web part jslink property to the file and
5. zippo. nothing happened.

Thanks

Comment: The JSLink you copied is of what type view/form/field? Can you share the URL of the file?

Answer (score 4):

Client Side Rendering (CSR) that was introduced in SharePoint 2013 should work the same way no matter is it a public site or a private site collection. The below figure demonstrates the customized List View for a Blogs public site.

**How to apply the changes**

Let's say we need to customizes Blog list view in order to display `Read more` links for a public site.

1. Create a rendering template, lets name it `Blogs.js` You could grab
   it from [here](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/8744426)
2. Upload JavaScript file into `Site Assets` library
3. Open Blog home page in `Edit` mode (Edit page). Specify for Posts
   web part JS Link property:

   ```
   ~sitecollection/SiteAssets/Blogs.js
   ```

   [image]

That's it.

**Result**

[image]